# How to show tooltip when has overridden mouse_enter event (WPF)?

Tags: wpf, tooltip, overriding

I have customized a taskbarnotifier follow this project: [WPF Taskbar Notifier - A WPF Taskbar Notification](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22876/WPF-Taskbar-Notifier-A-WPF-Taskbar-Notification-Wi) 
In this, author has overridden mouse enter event for hold window position in bottom right screen when mouse over on the notifier. I think that is the reason why I can't show Tooltip of any item in notifier when mouse over it. I use tooltip to show some text too long to display.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem, plz?

```
protected override void OnMouseEnter(System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DisplayState == DisplayStates.Opened)
        {
            // When the user mouses over and the window is already open, it should stay open.
            // Stop the timer that would have otherwise hidden it.
            this.stayOpenTimer.Stop();
        }
        else if ((this.DisplayState == DisplayStates.Hidden) ||
                 (this.DisplayState == DisplayStates.Hiding))
        {
            // When the user mouses over and the window is hidden or hiding, it should open. 
            this.DisplayState = DisplayStates.Opening;
        }

        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }
```